# Problema csrf_token modelos generados admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Como puedo poner `{% csrf_token %}` a los formularios que genero en el admin de Django, tengo este problema sobre estos formularios y no se como editarlos por que he consultado y la solución es poner `{% csrf_token %}` en los formularios.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son esos formularios de los que hablas? ¿Puedes mostrar el código que estás utilizando? ¿Te está dando algún error?

Answer (score 3):

El `{% csrf_token %}` va en los templates (archivos .html), donde está tu formulario, vendría a ser algo asi:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <span>Inicia sesión!</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

si usas el admin... ya te lo pone por defecto

para formularios hechos a mano va luego del tag form

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<!--aqui los input-->
</form>
```

fijáte que tengas habilitado el middleware 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' en el settings.py

Comment: pues no se que estara pasando, pero este error me esta pasando cuando quiero crear un registro a cualquiera de mis modelos desde el admin. en local esto no me sucede pero cuando lo despliego en cloud 9 es donde me sucede esta situación.

Answer (score 1):

podrias comentar esta linea en el archivo settings '`django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`'
sin embargo haces que tu aplicación este vulnerable a este ataque, es mejor usar algo como esto:

```
<pre>
<form action="/tupost/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<!--campos de formulario-->
</form>
</pre>
```